# Trying to delete a single task but when I try it deletes all tasks in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Why all tasks are removed instead of just the one I clicked.
To remove each task I'm using the filter() Array method and in my case, it removes all tasks in my list.
What would be a better option to remove single items if there is a better one or should I keep using filter()? Thanks for the help.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.scss";

const Todo = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [task, setTask] = useState("");

  const addTodo = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setTodos([...todos, task]);
    setTask("");
    // setId(Math.random())

    console.log(task, "(task)");
    console.log(todos, "(todos)");
  };

  const removeTodo = (task) => {
    setTodos(todos.filter((todo) => todo.task !== task));

    console.log(task);
  };

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
  // });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>To-Do Tasks</h1>
      <form onSubmit={addTodo}>
        <input value={task} onChange={(e) => setTask(e.target.value)} />
        <button>Add task</button>
      </form>
      {todos.map((todo) => (
        <div key={todo.task} id={todo.task}>
          <h4>{todo}</h4>
          <button onClick={() => removeTodo(todo.task)}>X</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Todo;
```

Comment: You code looks fine :) try setting id's not by  using Math.random()...but by  id:new Date().getTime().toString() .  I would like to know about your todo object {id: task:"value"} as well to help you best

Comment: your todo is just an array of strings, not array of objects, you don't have .task there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, you are storing todos as a simple array and not like an object, that's why you are having this problem.

Use this code instead:

Your removeTodo function should look like this:

```
const removeTodo = (task) => {
    setTodos(todos.filter((todo) => todo !== task));
    console.log(task);
  };
```

and pass the `todo` item, to `removeTodo()` instead of `todo.task`:

```
{todos.map((todo) => (
        <div key={todo.task} id={todo.task}>
          <h4>{todo}</h4>
          <button onClick={() => removeTodo(todo)}>X</button>
        </div>
      ))}
```

Answer (score 1):

`todos` is an array of strings. Your filter function checks for a `task` property that doesn't exist. Either add a `todo` as an object (`setTodos([...todos, {task}])`) or check the `todo` directly (`todos.filter((todo) => todo !== task)`).